# Issue while loading multiple Spring JPA context

Tags: spring, jpa

We are develpoing a application for fetching data from two separate databases[Mssql/Sybase].We are using Spring JPA (OpenJPA implementation) to interact with both databases. We used two different context files(Mssqlcontext.java and SybaseContext.java) for each DB. We have set separate profile name in context files(MsSqlProfile/SybaseProfile). We needs to conditionally load the context files based on our configuration. But the details of which database is configured is specified in an seperate configuration xml file. XML file is read as part of a bean. We are loading context using @import  annotation. JPA expects to give correct DB details while loading a context. But the context is imported before reading the configuration file. So we can't provide the correct database details.

The main problem that are trying to solve is that the Spring application should not crash if any of the database is not configured.

We tried to load the configuration bean before importing the context by implementing the following

1. Condition
2. ImportSelector
3. DeferredImportSelector
4. Ordered

However these are not working as expected.

**Sample code**

```
        public class SampleServiceInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
        {
            /**
             * Register the Spring configuration.
             */
            public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
            {

                AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
                ....
                ....
                ctx.register(SampleServiceConfiguration.class);
                ....
                ....

            }
        }

        @Import(SampleControllerConfiguration.class)
        public class SampleServiceConfiguration
        { 
            @Bean(name = configurationBean)
            @Scope("singleton")
            public ConfigRegistration getConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigRegistration config = new ConfigRegistration();
                config.init();
                // Here we read the configurations and set the profile name(SyabseProfile/MssqlProfile)
                return config;
            }

        }


        @Import({ SampleDataSourceConfiguration.class, SampleRequestorConfiguration.class })
        public class SampleControllerConfiguration
        {
        ....
        ....
        }


        @Import({ MSSqlContext.class, SybaseContext.class })
        public class SampleDataSourceConfiguration
        {
        ....
        ....
        }

        @Configuration
        @Profile(MsSqlProfile)
        ....
        ....
        public class MSSqlContext
        {
        ....
        ....
        }


        @Configuration
        @Profile(SybaseProfile)
        ....
        ....
        public class SybaseContext
        {
        ....
        ....
        }
```

In the above sample code MSSqlContext and SybaseContext is initialized before the configurationBean.

Comment: Why is it in a configuration file? Why not simply a properties file or environment variable. Do you really need it to be an an xml file.

Comment: This is a service application. We have many service related configuration which we keep in this xml file. So to be consistent, we keep the DB information also in the XML..

Comment: That isn't the problem, the issue is why do you need to profile information in XML also. Simply set it as an environment variable `-Dspring.profiles.active=mysql` for instance (or JNDI or...) that way you can load the configuration in one go.

Comment: We planned to set the profile names depending on the attribute value of xml. Is there any other solution for this issue? If not we can proceed as you mentioned above.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that everything needs to be loaded before you are setting the profile, that is not how profiles work. They need to be set before the context is loaded/initialized. As a workaround you could create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which loads your xml file containing the profile information, then programmatically set the profiles before loading the context. Although I would consider this a hack and I would simply go with the defaults.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The basic problem that we are trying to solve here is how do we handle multiple JPA context with one DB not configured. Is Profile the best approrach here ? If yes, then I would think of putting the profile information in a property file rather than the XML as you suggested.

Comment: With profiles you can basically make a selection of what is loaded when. Also what is the difference? Only the DB or also the table structure? If it is only the db information then why do you need 2 contexts, then just put the db information in a properties file and have a single jpa config...

Comment: Actually the 2 DBs (Mssql and Sybase) are having different table structure. We will need to have different repositories for each of them.

Comment: Ok. Then just use a profile and use an environment variable or `ApplicationContextInitializer` to set the profile.

Comment: Thank you. Will proceed with Profiles then. I have one more doubt regarding JPA connection. If the DB is down when the Spring application boots up, the Spring application does not start. It fails with exception from JPA.  But my servcie has many other features which should work even if the JPA DB is down. Is there a way to make Spring not crash even if the DB is not up ?

Comment: that depends on the datasource generally if it is a pool it will create some connections at startup. If that fails your application fails, next to that generally your JPA provider also needs a database connection to be able to build the mappings (and do some checks).

Comment: I have already registered this issue in the following link.
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323741/handle-expection-when-an-invalid-database-is-configured-using-spring-jpa 
  
  can you refer the link?